# java regex , extract a line?

Tags: java, regex, multiline

given 3 lines , how can I extract 2nd line using regular expression ?

```
line1
line2
line3
```

I used

```
pattern = Pattern.compile("line1.*(.*?).*line3");
```

But nothing appears

Comment: try the DOTALL option when compiling the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Pattern.DOTALL flag like this:

```
String str = "line1\nline2\nline3";
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("line1\n(.+?)\nline3", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = pt.matcher(str);
while (m.find())
    System.out.printf("Matched - [%s]%n", m.group(1)); // outputs [line2]
```

Comment: This seems extract \n , any way to remove them ?

Comment: In your example it worked , in my example it is still giving me the new lines . Any other ways to remove them ? I tried string = string.replaceAll("\\\\n", "");
 but didn't work

Comment: You can call replaceAll as well but if you use my updated RegEx then it won't even capture `\n` thus eliminating the need to call `replaceAll`

Answer (score 0):

This won't work, since your first `.*` matches everything up to line3. Your reluctant match gets lost, as does the second `.*`.
Try to specify the line breaks (^ and $) after line1 / before line3.

Answer (score 0):

Try `pattern = Pattern.compile("line1.*?(.*?).*?line3", Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.MULTILINE);`

Comment: I don't think this works - won't the reluctant group in the middle will resolve to 0 characters?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract everything between two non-empty lines:

```
(?<=.+\n).+(?=\n.+)
```